# MariaDB Triggers error for getting length of name

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I am trying to see if the length of a name in my library table is the allowed length.
This is my trigger but it's giving me an error. I have a table called membership and it has a column called name, for the name of each person with a membership.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is my trigger:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE msg varchar(100);
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF len(membership.name) NOT between 4 and 20 THEN
set msg ='Name should be between 5 and 20 letters'; 
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
END IF;
END
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> The following query has failed: "CREATE TRIGGER `Student_Name` BEFORE
> INSERT ON `membership` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DECLARE msg varchar(100);
> FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF len(membership.name) NOT between 4 and 20 THEN
> set msg ='Name should be between 5 and 20 letters'; SET MESSAGE_TEXT =
> msg; END IF; END "
>
> MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'EACH ROW BEGIN IF len(membership.name) NOT between
> 4 and 20 THEN set msg ='...' at line 3

Comment: It looks like you have repeated "FOR EACH ROW BEGIN" unnecessarily. Copy & paste error?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I see what you mean but I don't have that in my code repeated so I'm unsure of what the error means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the syntax for CREATE TRIGGER: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-trigger/

You must use FOR EACH ROW only once, before the body of the trigger.

You have also used FOR EACH ROW a second time, after your DECLARE line. Take that out.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Student_Name BEFORE INSERT ON membership
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 DECLARE msg varchar(100);
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN <---- remove this line
 IF LENGTH(NEW.name) NOT between 4 and 20 THEN
  SET msg ='Name should be between 5 and 20 letters'; 
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
 END IF;
END
```

There are other problems too.

This row:

```
 IF len(membership.name) NOT between 4 and 20 THEN
```

There is no LEN() function. See [LENGTH()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/length/).

If you want to refer to the value of the `name` column in the new row you are inserting, use `NEW.name`.

If you want to refer to the column `name` of the new row inserted, use `NEW.name`, not `membership.name`.

You probably also want to use the MESSAGE_TEXT somehow to abort the insert in case of a conflict with your rule. You probably intended to use [SIGNAL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/signal/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am still getting an error after making the changes. I don't know what is wrong. Here is my code:                                                                                                                       
```CREATE TRIGGER Student_Name 
BEFORE INSERT ON membership
 BEGIN
 DECLARE msg varchar(100);
  IF LENGTH(NEW.name) NOT between 5 and 20 THEN
 set msg ='Name should be between 5 and 20 letters'; 
 SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
 END IF;
END```

Comment: The error is on line 3 it said by the way.

Comment: My mistake, in my example I removed both instance of "FOR EACH ROW". I've edited my answer above to put one back in, _before_ the BEGIN.

Comment: I also added a note about using SIGNAL.